# Tips on creating user interfaces and optimizing the user experience

Tags: user-interface, optimization, user-experience

I am currently working on a project where a lot of user interaction is going to take place. There is also a commercial side as people can buy certain items and services.

In my opinion a good blend of user interface, speed and security is essential for these types of websites. It is fairly easy to use ajax and JavaScript nowadays to do almost everything, as there are a lot of libraries available such as jQuery and others. But this can have some performance and incompatibility issues. This can lead to users just going to the next website.

The overall look of the website is important too. Where to place certain buttons, where to place certain types of articles such as faq and support. Where and how to display error messages so that the user sees them but are not bothering him. And an overall color scheme is important too.

The basic question is: ***How to create an interface that triggers a user to buy/use your services***

I know psychology also plays a huge role in how users interact with your website. The color scheme for example is important. When the colors are irritating on a website you just want to click away. I have not found any articles that explain those concept.

Does anyone have any tips and/or recourses where i can get some articles that guide you in making the correct choices for your website.

Comment: Read Steve Krug's book: *[Don't Make Me Think: A Common Sense Approach to Web Usability](http://www.sensible.com/dmmt.html)*

Answer (score 7):

Adhere to some standard UI Design Principles:

1. **The structure principle:** Your design
   should organize the user interface
   purposefully, in meaningful and
   useful ways based on clear,
   consistent models that are apparent
   and recognizable to users, putting
   related things together and
   separating unrelated things,
   differentiating dissimilar things
   and making similar things resemble
   one another. The structure principle
   is concerned with your overall user
   interface architecture.
2. **The simplicity principle:** Your
   design should make simple, common
   tasks simple to do, communicating
   clearly and simply in the user’s own
   language, and providing good
   shortcuts that are meaningfully
   related to longer procedures.
3. **The visibility principle:** Your
   design should keep all needed
   options and materials for a given
   task visible without distracting the
   user with extraneous or redundant
   information. Good designs don’t
   overwhelm users with too many
   alternatives or confuse them with
   unneeded information.
4. **The feedback principle:** Your design
   should keep users informed of
   actions or interpretations, changes
   of state or condition, and errors or
   exceptions that are relevant and of
   interest to the user through clear,
   concise, and unambiguous language
   familiar to users.
5. **The tolerance principle:** Your design
   should be flexible and tolerant,
   reducing the cost of mistakes and
   misuse by allowing undoing and
   redoing, while also preventing
   errors wherever possible by
   tolerating varied inputs and
   sequences and by interpreting all
   reasonable actions reasonable.
6. **The reuse principle:** Your design
   should reuse internal and external
   components and behaviors,
   maintaining consistency with purpose
   rather than merely arbitrary
   consistency, thus reducing the need
   for users to rethink and remember.

Try to look for Websites or Web Application which has successfully achieved the goal you are looking to achieve, study their UI's, try to find common parameters & patterns which engages the user on their sites.

I always believe [amazon](http://www.amazon.com) is very good at keeping user engaged on website by showing **relevant recommendations**, `what other people are looking` types recommendations, `people who bought this also bought this` kind of recommendations.

Another good read: [What should a developer know about interface design usability and user psychology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326925/what-should-a-developer-know-about-interface-design-usability-and-user-psycholog)

Also, [Good Read](http://designreviver.com/tips/vital-tips-for-effective-ecommerce-website-design/) on UI design considerations of e-commerce websites.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to UI design, ideally you will have an actual visual designer provide some guidance on your use of colors and a UxD provide some insight into your layout and flows based upon their expertise in these areas. Barring these folks having some input, if you design the pages and create the visuals yourself, iterative discovery is the best method to inform your design and provide insight into how these items affect the user and the overall experience you have created.

While there are certainly numerous books you can read and "guidelines" you can follow (and should for the initial design phases), no amount of book learning can replace real user interactions.

Build a functional prototype of your site/app/service/etc. and get it in front of actual users to gauge usability and value.  This should be done in an ad-hoc format (versus formal usability testing) and the prototype should consist of smoke and mirrors as needed (i.e. it could be only clickable comps or primarily images with only the flows you're testing actually working).

Once you have some level of prototype, bring it to a place where ppl tend to be (and where you have i-net access if needed).  I have found Starbucks to be great for this. Grab some ppl and ask if you can have 10 minutes of their time - you'll find tons of willing participants.  Provide these folks with a simple / specific scenario to complete in your prototype and watch and learn.

People in a real-world situation using your software will quickly find its flaws and you'll be learning more than you could ever glean from a book or guideline. You'll be iterating on the design and tweaking items every time you test.

Test like this over a few weeks and you'll be discovering the perfect design very quickly. Once you have something that ppl can use and find value in, you're ready to get it live. But, testing should not end there - once live, you should continue to test and tweak via A/B and multi-variant testing while keeping a close eye on on your analytics and user behavior.

Discovery testing followed continual A/B allows you to continuously tweak, test and learn and ultimately to create the best solution possible.